# How to only run CircleCI on GitHub master branch?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I have a CircleCI build task on GitHub that I only want to run on the `master` branch, however it's currently running on every single branch. Is there something wrong with my `config.yml`?

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: 'cimg/python:3.6'
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-s3/sync:
          arguments: '--delete'
          aws-access-key-id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws-region: AWS_REGION
          aws-secret-access-key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          from: src
          to: 's3://somebucket'
workflows:
  s3-sync:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  build:
    branches:
      only:
        - main
```

This syntax is deprecated but it may help to fix the issue for you.

Comment: Came across this...unfortunately it doesn't validate with the new syntax